# HTML/CSS/JS: If I list several mp4 videos on a sidebar, how could I create a webpage where the video opens in the main part of the page when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, mp4

I am trying to create a-single page similar to a module in Udemy or Khan Academy.

I have gathered ~20 videos that I want to begin with.

I looked at the code for Udemy and Khan Academy and it appears that the side bar that lists the different lessons of a module is just an unordered list with anchor tags.

But I cannot figure out how to play those videos in the main part of the page when I click on them.

I should also note that I a m trying to do this using only HTML and CSS since I am still very new with JS.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"But I cannot figure out how to play those videos in the main part of the page when I click on them."_ When you create something (text/list items) you can assign a related `onClick` function. You'll need one `<video>` tag and a function like `changeVid (someURL);` which is given some url (as a function parameter) and that function can change the video tag's url with `yourVideoTag.src = someURL;`. Each item or text name's `onClick` calls `changeVid ( with_some_MP4_link_here)` so the function refers to it as `someURL` and gives it to the video tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Johannes and @VC.One. I actually figured out what I was trying to do by using jQuery.

Step 1 - I created an HTML file with a container div, a row div, and two column divs.

Step 2 - The first column div was the main part where my video would play. I embedded an iframe with the source being a url to the video.

step 3 - I used the second column to create an unordered list ul, and I listed 7 list items li. I then gave each li an id.

Step 4 - I used CSS to make each

clickable by changing the cursor to pointer on hover ex: li:hover {cursor:pointer}

Step 5 - Finally, I used jQuery to change the source attribute of the iframe by whenever I clicked on an li.

```js
$("#video1").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JSDuy7v73wI");
});

$("#video2").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/DxREm3s1scA");
});

$("#video3").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6JipQNWuYnA");
});

$("#video4").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/w_DKWlrA24k");
});

$("#video5").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zmBWPLShmXI");
});

$("#video6").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KoHG6kKxJas");
});

$("#video7").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/OT8w4dx_N8U");
});

$("#video8").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/r4xp1nq_suc");
});
```

```css
.box2 {
    background-color: #f7f9fa;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.video-table {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.video-lessons {
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: black;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.video-lessons:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#d1d7dc;
}

.iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.responsive-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>video1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/video1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box1 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-11">
                    <div class="iframe-container">
                        <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JSDuy7v73wI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    
                
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs navigation-table" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Q&A" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Q&A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Resources" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Resources</a>
                         </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="Q&A" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                            <textarea name="" id="" cols="100" rows="10" placeholder="Ask the community a question"></textarea>
                            <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Resources" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                            <p>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                            <p>Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade. Messenger bag gentrify pitchfork tattooed craft beer, iphone skateboard locavore carles etsy salvia banksy hoodie helvetica. DIY synth PBR banksy irony. Leggings gentrify squid 8-bit cred pitchfork. Williamsburg banh mi whatever gluten-free, carles pitchfork biodiesel fixie etsy retro mlkshk vice blog. Scenester cred you probably haven't heard of them, vinyl craft beer blog stumptown. Pitchfork sustainable tofu synth chambray yr.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="box2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-1">
                    <ul class="video-table">
                        <li class="video-lessons"><h5>Course Content</h5></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video1"><p>1. How ethereum works and other things to consider</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video2"><p>2. An Interview with Elon Musk about the future</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video3"><p>3. Reference material for plasma physics</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video4"><p>4. Reference material for plasma physics</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video5"><p>5. Another broken video link</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video6"><p>6. Zendaya saying something about her bf</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video7"><p>7. Some broken video about something</p></li>
                        <li class="video-lessons" id="video8"><p>8. Hawk stares his resuer down</p></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <script src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="JS/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with HTML/CSS only (except the completely outdated concept of framesets). What you need for this is a script (Javascript/jQuery or similar) which loads the desired video/s into the main section on click, changing/updating the HTML code of that section. For a more detailed description you would have to post the exact HTML code of your page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I suspected that I would need to use JS/JQuery but thought I would ask the community just to make sure. Thank you so much!